# Android Studio - Code Coverage when using Espresso

Tags: android, jacoco, android-espresso

I'm building an Android Studio App and I want to generate some code coverage statistics for instrumentation tests using Espresso.

I'm running ./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport from the command line. It successfully reports which tests passed/failed, but it always says I have 0% code coverage. The coverage.ec file that is generated is always empty.

Here is my build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "exampleId"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0'
}
```

I'm fairly certain that it has something to do with Espresso, because I created another Project and everything worked fine as long as I excluded

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
```

The coverage report was generated successfully.

I've looked around online extensively for this, but I'm unable to find a solution that works for me.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thank you so much Emma! After updating

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
```

To

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
```

The code coverage report appeared correctly. I don't know what the issue was originally, but this seems to have resolved it.

Comment: I had the same issue with 2.2 and when I upgraded espresso to 2.2.1, it worked.